# Get cache path for Unity on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, caching, android-storage

I try to retreive a path to cache in Unity on Android without using the native code. I thought that I could use  [Application.temporaryCachePath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-temporaryCachePath.html).

This method returns the path: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.<myapp>/cache`.

But when I use native Android code I see it should be: `/data/user/0/com.<myapp>/cache`.

Is there any way to retrieve in Unity the path to the cache which is used by Android native code? The only working workaround I found is:

```cs
AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
string cache = jo.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getCacheDir").Call<string>("getCanonicalPath");
```

It returns the expected path to `/data/data/com.<myapp>/cache`.

Any suggestions to use something cleaner than embedding android native code into c# like above? Maybe the Unity app is configured incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Application.persistentDataPath`. It points to `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/files` on Android. Also, you can use it on other platforms and it will point to a valid cache path. Check the unity docs for more details -> [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html)

Comment: But the cache in Android is under /data/user/0/<packagename>/cache

Comment: I'm sure that the files are under Application.persistentDataPath (On my Xiaomi Poco: Android-> data -> your package name: <com>.<company>.<name>) are caches.

Comment: The path you reference to is external-cache-path corresponding with Context.getExternalCacheDir().I’m looking for cache-path corresponding with Context.getCacheDir().  (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider )